# How to Decode Multidimensional Json Array in PHP

Tags: php, json

Someone help me on how to loop through my JSON file below and retrieve all values in a loop, am only able to get the first occurrence.

```
$someJSON ='[{"sender":"SENDER1","phone":"442","message":"Test Message 1","correlator":"101","link_id":null,"endpoint":null},{"sender":"SENDER22","phone":"442","message":"Test Message 1","correlator":"101","link_id":null,"endpoint":null}]';

//   Convert JSON string to Array
     $someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);
  
  foreach( $someArray as $record){
       //echo $record[0]->sender; // Access Object data
        echo $record["sender"]; //LOOP ALL
}
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output. you can get all of first occurrence print $record.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question, I just wanted to get the sender, phone, and message as a string value.

Here is my solution

```
<?php
//  header("Content-Type: application/json");
 
//$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$json ='[{"sender":"SENDER1","phone":"637986554433","message":"Test Message 1","correlator":"101","link_id":null,"endpoint":null},{"sender":"SENDER2","phone":"254798655431","message":"Test Message 2","correlator":"102","link_id":null,"endpoint":null}]';

  $responses = json_decode($json , true);
  
   //print_r($response);
   
foreach ($responses as $row) {
     $phone = $row ['phone'];
     echo $phone;
     echo '<br>';
}
```